# SNOWFLAKE Sequence Creation Issue

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence, primary-key, auto-increment

In SNOWFLAKE database, I was trying to create 2 sequences under same name but with case sensitive and for one sequence I was trying to increment by 1 and the other sequence I was trying to increment based on the value from staging table.

To explain better.

The below screenshot is the current sequence list in my SNOWFLAKE database, now I want to add two new sequences called scholarid (Small letters) with increment by 1 and create another sequence called SCHLARID (Captial Letters) with increment by next value (**428846**) generated from another table.

[image]

I tried creating the first sequence with small letters but it gets created in the list only as Capital letters and when I try to create the second one with Capital letters, it throws an error as below

[image]

I am not sure why I am not able to create 2 sequnces like something similar to AddressID (One with lower case and incremented by 1 and other with Capital letters and incremented in 44846)

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifiers are automatically converted into uppercase if you do not specify any quotes.

You have to use "AddressID" to have the final name AdressID and not ADDRESSID.